How to create a spring boot client that consumes the HTTP Post response from a webhook
I am new to webhooks and don't completely understand how they work. If I have a server-side webhook to which a client has registered. Upon an event, the webhook is triggered and a HTTP Post request with JSON payload is sent on the web-hook URL. My question is how can I implement a simple client in Spring boot that will consume the JSON payload sent by server via webhook URL?
I looked at some tutorials for web-hook but didn't any examples of clients consuming the HTTP Post response.
